# How to call a method when Countdown OnFinish from another activity?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a class that has a CountDownTimer, which will be use throughout my project and I want to call different methods upon the Countdown onFinish() from different activities.

Here's my CountDownTimer class;

```
public class CountDownTimer {

    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 10000;
    private long timeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    private final TextView textViewCountDown;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean timerRunning;

    public CountDownTimer(TextView textView) {
        this.textViewCountDown = textView;
        startTimer();
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new android.os.CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timerRunning = false;
            }
        }.start();
        timerRunning = true;
    }

    public void resetTimer() {
        timeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
    }

    public void pauseTimer() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timerRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Example Scenario - Once a specific activity prompted, countdown will start and user has 10s to do whatever he wants otherwise it will automatically collect data and validate. So, once the 10s is over validating and data collecting methods should call from the activity.

I am a newbie to Android Dev and Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways to achive this, each of them with different preferences. For your usecase i guess you could look into [Broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts). Have all Activities that need to perform an action after the countdown implement a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) which reacts to the Broadcast sent by your CountDownTimer.

Another option would be to implement some way of eventhandling. Android doesn't provide a event API, but you could look into the [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) lib. Alternatively you could also just write your own event framework. For a simple case like yours it shouldn't be to complex.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where I have to call methods/functions from other places in the application I make use of interfaces.

For example:

Here is an activity:

```java
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RemoteRunner.RemoteRunnerCallback{
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

        RemoteRunner remoteRunnerObject = new RemoteRunner(this); 
        remoteRunnerObject.runExternalMethod(); // <--- This part calls the showMessage() function

    }

    private void showMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this, message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoteCalled(String message)

}
```

I want to run a method in `SomeActivity` from this class:

```java
public class RemoteRunner{
    
    public interface RemoteRunnerCallback{
        void onRemoteCalled(String message);
    }

    private RemoteRunnerCallback remoteRunnerListener;
    
    public RemoteRunner(RemoteRunnerCallback remoteRunnerListener){
        this.remoteRunnerListener = remoteRunnerListener;
    }

    public void runExternalMethod(){
        remoteRunnerListener.onRemoteCalled("This message is from RemoteRunner");
    }

}
```